# Kali linux wi-fi adapter not found

Tags: kali-linux, realtek

i'm running new (2019.3) kali live from pendrive. And this one doesn't find my wifi adapter (previous were finding). I have a asus noteook so wifi adapter is built in.

```
lspci
```

says that i have RTL8822BE 802.112/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter.
I have red a lot of manuals, can someone explain me how to fix this out?

Comment: `I have red a lot of manuals` ... manuals about what?

Comment: Kali is notorious for having trouble with Wifi drivers. If you want to learn Linux and hacking, read [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me), and use some other Debian-based distro (Kali is Debian-based) for all the hacking tools Kali has (though you have to install them) and none of the trouble. Kali is not "what all the hackers use", no matter what you read on some forums.

Comment: What kernel are you using?

Comment: I have the newest one - kernel 5.2.9

Answer (score 2):

Since kernel 5.2.x, RTL8822BE switched to RTW88 driver.
Make sure RTW88 is loaded:

```
lsmod | grep rtw88
```

Then make sure there is a correct firmware file in your `/lib/firmware/rtw88/`

If not, you may get it from e.g.:

```
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/rtw88/rtw8822b_fw.bin
```

Comment: Last question, do rtw88 has to be git cloned or just downloaded?

Comment: The firmware bin file can be just downloaded.

Comment: The rtw88 driver should be part of the kernel. It depends on the exact compilation setup.

Comment: Thank you for help