# No wireless connection on Kali installation

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, kali-linux, realtek

I have just installed Kali Linux (64) on my laptop, but I haven't been able to get the Wi-Fi to work.

These are what I'm getting when I run the following commands:

iwconfig

```py
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

ifconfig

```py
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.60  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::82e8:2cff:fe74:3ba0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 80:e8:2c:74:3b:a0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 15636  bytes 18745879 (17.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 152  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8973  bytes 1048734 (1.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 20  bytes 1116 (1.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20  bytes 1116 (1.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

airmon-ng

```py
PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset
```

lspci

```py
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 10)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #14 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #15 (rev f0)
00:1d.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #16 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30d (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f91 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Device 1327
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Alcor Micro Device 6625
05:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
```

Comment: You need RTW88 driver a proper firmware file. Have a look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548788/kali-linux-wi-fi-adapter-not-found

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Diego !
For RTL8822BE, Larry Finger has developped a driver `rtlwifi_new`. It works on Ubuntu and Linux Mint but not fully sure it will work on Kali (I do not have tested on Kali).
Here the procedure to install the driver:

Install packages required for the building of the driver:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git
```

and then

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88
cd rtw88
make
sudo make install
```

You can find more information here: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88
You should check if this driver is compatible with your current kernel.

Comment: @GAD3R, thanks for the edition ;)