# i cannot connect to wifi in kali linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, network-interface

I installed kali linux in my PC. My wifi adapter is Realtek RTL8822BE 802.11ac PCLe Adapter.

It is working properly in Windows but not in Kali.

Running `ifconfig`: it is not showing wlan0. Only l0 and eth0 are shown.

Running iwconfig: the output is:

```
l0: no wireless extensions.
eth0: no wireless extensions.
```

I tried installing wireless drives, but no use.

Comment: Is this a VM or a bare metal install?

Comment: What wireless drivers did you install? How did you install them? What kernel version are you running?

Comment: not in vmware@kemotep

Comment: You need RTW88 driver a proper firmware file. Have a look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548788/kali-linux-wi-fi-adapter-not-found

Answer (score -1):

You can do a few things from the terminal:

`nm-connection-editor` 
 and add a new connection with wireless, or use `nmtui` for the configuration of your wireless adapter. 
 Apart from that check whether you have such a device with `nmcli dev status`

Comment: The OP has already said that `ifconfig` doesn't list the adapter interface